# ODOO Aplicant kanban view add text under stage name

Tags: view, odoo, odoo-14, kanban

I am trying to add a text or field name under the stage name in the Applicant kanban view. please refer the below image for the reference. I want to add a text where i marked in red line.
[image]
from the user interface i am trying edit the kanban view , I created new view in the Inherited Views,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xpath expr="//span[@class='o_column_title']" position="after">
    <field name="display_name"></field>
</xpath>
```

But I am getting this error

```
Error while validating view:

Element '<xpath expr="//span[@class='o_column_title']">' cannot be located in parent view

View name: my_kanban_view
Error context:
 view: ir.ui.view(662,)
 view.model: hr.applicant
 view.parent: ir.ui.view(566,)
```

Can you please guide me to achieve this? I will be very useful for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you try to locate is part of the [KanbanView.Group](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/static/src/xml/kanban.xml#L11) template which is rendered in the [kanban column](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/static/src/js/views/kanban/kanban_column.js#L19).

You need to inherit that template to add an element just after the title.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates>
    <t t-inherit="web.KanbanView.Group" t-inherit-mode="primary">
        <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('o_kanban_header_title')]" position="after">
           
        </xpath>
    </t>
</templates>
```

You can check the kanban column js file to see the available variables defined in the column widget. Records are grouped in each column and available in the `data_records` object (*`widget.data_records`*).
You will need to select a record before you try to access the field value.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225803/discussion-on-answer-by-kenly-odoo-aplicant-kanban-view-add-text-under-stage-nam).